# Working with EditorTemplates and radio buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am showing data in tabular format. the table is generated automatically when working with **EditorFor and EditorTemplates**.

in each row of table i am showing ID, Name, Country dropdown, checkboxes for hobbies selection and radio button for sex selection.

all are working fine but i am not being able to bind radio buttons for sex.
i am not being able to understand what i am missing for which i am getting error.

please have a look at my code and give me direction what to change for radio buttons.

### my full code

**controller code**

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            StudentListViewModel osvm = new StudentListViewModel();
            osvm.Sex = osvm.GetSex();
            osvm.Countries = osvm.GetCountries();
            return View(osvm);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(StudentListViewModel oStudentListViewModel)
        {
            return View(oStudentListViewModel);
        }
}
```

### viewmodel

```
public class StudentListViewModel
{
    //public List<Country> Country { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }

    public IList<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public List<Sex> Sex { get; set; }

    public StudentListViewModel()
    {
        Students = new List<Student>
        {
            new Student
            {
                ID=1,Name="Keith",CountryID="0",SexID="F",
                Hobbies= new List<Hobby>
                {
                    new Hobby{ID=1,Name="Football",Checked=true},
                    new Hobby{ID=2,Name="Hocky",Checked=false},
                    new Hobby{ID=3,Name="Cricket",Checked=false}
                }

            },

            new Student
            {
                ID=2,Name="Paul",CountryID="2",
                Hobbies= new List<Hobby>
                {
                    new Hobby{ID=1,Name="Football",Checked=false},
                    new Hobby{ID=2,Name="Hocky",Checked=true},
                    new Hobby{ID=3,Name="Cricket",Checked=false}
                }
            },

            new Student
            {
                ID=3,Name="Sam",CountryID="3",
                Hobbies= new List<Hobby>
                {
                    new Hobby{ID=1,Name="Football",Checked=false},
                    new Hobby{ID=2,Name="Hocky",Checked=false},
                    new Hobby{ID=3,Name="Cricket",Checked=true}
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public List<Sex> GetSex()
    {
        Sex = new List<Sex>
        {
            new Sex{ID="M",SexName="Male"},
            new Sex{ID="F",SexName="Female"}
        };

        return Sex;
    }

    public List<SelectListItem> GetCountries()
    {
        Countries = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem{Value="1",Text="India"},
            new SelectListItem{Value="2",Text="UK"},
            new SelectListItem{Value="3",Text="USA"}
        };

        return Countries;
    }
}
```

### Model class

```
   public class Student
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string CountryID { get; set; }
        public string SexID { get; set; }
        public IList<Hobby> Hobbies { get; set; }

    }

    public class Hobby
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Checked { get; set; }
    }

    public class Sex
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string SexName { get; set; }
    }
```

### Main View Index.cshtml

```
@model EditorTemplateSample.Models.StudentListViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<br /><br />
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        ID
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Country
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Hobbies
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Sex
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tbody>
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Students, new { Countries = Model.Countries, Sex = Model.Sex })
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**EditorTemplates\Student.cshtml**

```
@model EditorTemplateSample.Models.Student
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryID,
            new SelectList((List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Countries"], "Value", "Text", Model.CountryID), "-- Select Country--")
    <td>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Hobbies)
    <td>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => ((EditorTemplateSample.Models.Sex) ViewData["Sex"]).ID)
    <td>
</tr>
```

**EditorTemplates\Hobby.cshtml**

```
@model EditorTemplateSample.Models.Hobby

<div class="checkbox">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Checked)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Checked, Model.Name)
</div>
```

**EditorTemplates\Sex.cshtml**

```
@model EditorTemplateSample.Models.Sex
<td>
    <div class="checkbox">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => ((EditorTemplateSample.Models.Sex)ViewData["Sex"]).ID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => ((EditorTemplateSample.Models.Sex)ViewData["Sex"]).SexName)
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => ((EditorTemplateSample.Models.Sex)ViewData["Sex"]).ID, ((EditorTemplateSample.Models.Sex)ViewData["Sex"]).ID)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => ((EditorTemplateSample.Models.Sex)ViewData["Sex"]).ID, ((EditorTemplateSample.Models.Sex)ViewData["Sex"]).SexName)
    </div>
</td>
```

`@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Students, new { Countries = Model.Countries, Sex = Model.Sex })` the above way i pass Sex model data to Student.cshtml file

from Student.cshtml file i try to bind ID `@Html.EditorFor(m => ((EditorTemplateSample.Models.Sex) ViewData["Sex"]).ID)`

**in EditorTemplates\sex.cshtml file**

```
@model EditorTemplateSample.Models.Sex
<td>
    <div class="checkbox">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => ((EditorTemplateSample.Models.Sex)ViewData["Sex"]).ID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => ((EditorTemplateSample.Models.Sex)ViewData["Sex"]).SexName)
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => ((EditorTemplateSample.Models.Sex)ViewData["Sex"]).ID, ((EditorTemplateSample.Models.Sex)ViewData["Sex"]).ID)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => ((EditorTemplateSample.Models.Sex)ViewData["Sex"]).ID, ((EditorTemplateSample.Models.Sex)ViewData["Sex"]).SexName)
    </div>
</td>
```

guide me how could i pass my sex data from main index view to sex view in **EditorTemplates** folder.

### Edit

in main view i add this line

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Students, new { Countries = Model.Countries, MainModel = Model, Sex = Model.Sex })
```

in student.cshtml i edit line like `@Html.EditorFor(m => ((EditorTemplateSample.Models.StudentListViewModel)ViewData["MainModel"]).Sex, new { Sex = (List<EditorTemplateSample.Models.Sex>)ViewData["Sex"] })`

in sex.cshtml for radio button generation i changed line likes

```
<div class="checkbox">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SexName)
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ID,Model.ID)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ID, Model.SexName)
</div>
```

but still no luck. badly stuck due to lack of control over asp.net mvc **EditorTemplates**  now radio buttons are coming but all are selected by default which is wrong. see the latest UI.

[image]

please help me to get out of this problem. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Student` class contains a property `string SexID` which is what you are wanting to bind the selected radio button value to. But your `EditorTemplate` is for a model that is typeof `Sex`, and you `Student` model does not contain a property which is typeof `Sex` (and nor should it).

Using an `EditorTemplate` in this case makes no sense - your binding to a simple property, not a complex object or collection of objects. The radio buttons should be generated in your `Student.cshtml` template.

```
@model EditorTemplateSample.Models.Student
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ID)
    </td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)</td>
    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryID, new SelectList((List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Countries"], "Value", "Text", Model.CountryID), "-- Select Country--")</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Hobbies)</td>
    <td>
        @foreach(var sex in (List<Sex>)ViewData["Sex"])
        {
            <label>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SexID, sex.ID, new { id = "" })
                <span>@sex.SexName</span>
            </label>
        }
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hello sir. still there is some issue which i discuss in this post. please have a look at my Edit 2 section and tell me what to add to fix those issue. thanks

Comment: Read [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) to understand the issue - you have not populated the `Counties` and `Sex` properties in the POST method before you return the view so they are `null`. And I have rolled back your edit (if you have a new question, then you need to ask a new question)

Comment: still i have issue. please see my edit 2 section. still no data are passing for countries and sex property to second index action when form submit. do not understand what is missing in my code. guide me please.

Comment: Again. I have rolled back your last edit. If you have a new question the ask a NEW question.

Comment: Sir i have post a new question for the same issue here is link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49038668/asp-net-mvc-view-model-properties-are-getting-null-when-form-submit  please share the knowlege. tell me how could i pass my country and sex data when form submit. thanks